# todos.unshift is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I try to add to the beginning of an array in React Native I get the following error:

```
TypeError: todos.unshift is not a function. (In 'todos.unshift(newTodo)', 'todos.unshift' is undefined)
```

My Code is :

```
export default function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(['Hello']);
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState('');

  function addItem(newTodo) {
    console.log(newTodo);
    setTodos(todos.unshift(newTodo));
  }

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={() => {
        Keyboard.dismiss();
      }}
    >
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder='new todo'
          style={styles.input}
          value={todo}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            setTodo(text);
          }}
        ></TextInput>
        <Button title='Add' onPress={()=>addItem(todo)}></Button>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
}
```

Why is this happening . Is useState not applying the type of todos as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

method 'unshift' does not return modified array. you can see how it works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift).

and mutating state without setState method is not recommend because in that case React cannot detect the change.

you can use `setTodos(arr => [newTodo, ...arr])` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this as the array 'unshift' method does not return a modified array.

Clone the state first using the spread operator and then update the state.

```
function addItem(newTodo) {
  let arrayToUpdate = [...todos];
  arrayToUpdate.unshift(newTodo);
  setTodos(arrayToUpdate);
}
```